What kind of green-leafed flower is this?
These flowers are growing in one of my tree beds.
I was wondering what kind they were.
I think they are some kind of annuals.
I'm trying to get rid of them.

This is in Pennsylvania, and the flowers bloom in spring.

Hi pmagunia, welcome to the site!  Do you happen to have any pictures of the flowers in bloom?

Hi @MackM - thank you for the welcome. Unfortunately I do not. I don't think I can get them in bloom until next spring. I do not know if it makes a difference but the flowers are located in Pennsylvania, USA.

Can we get a photo of the place where the leaves emerge, near the soil line? And if you are trying to eradicate them anyway, can you please dig up one and share what kind of roots they have? Or bulbs perhaps? (Also with a photo.) feel free to [edit] your post as needed. And if you can’t get a photo of the flowers, a verbal description is appreciated, if you can remember what they look like.

Sure let me try to get another photo. Things are busy right now during the week but I will try to get one over the weekend.

Those look like Lily of the Valley. A few key ID points when not in bloom - two long, pointy, medium to dark green leaves per stem, white horizontal roots about 2 inches below the soil surface, and roots that extend far from the stem, with darker nodes that also have roots. In bloom the flower looks like this.
This is not an easy plant to remove because you have to get all of the roots or the plant will resprout from one of the nodes.

Lily of the Valley, yes, a beautiful spreading shade plant with flowers of heavenly scent.

@YosefBaskin Yes they are, but their spreading nature and habit of spreading where no one wants them, such as nature preserves, has gotten them listed as an invasive species in my and many other US states. I have found that the pink-flowered form spreads less than the true species.

So far the plant hasn't spread to other parts of the lawn which I am thankful for. We have some healthy grass surrounding it which is keeping it isolated I think.

@pmagunia just a warning I've been issued when I was a tiny lad:
"Due to the concentration of cardiac glycosides (cardenolides), it is highly poisonous if consumed by humans or other animals." Neither our dog nor any of the cats were attracted to it though.

This may also be Allium ursinum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allium_ursinum), which is notoriously similar to Lily of the Valley. (This is significant because Allium ursinum is tasty, while Lily of the Valley is poisonous.)
They are easily distiguished by their flowers, and by the garlicky smell of the allium leaves.

A good suggestion. Particularly at the leaves are so seemingly random, whereas with lily of the valley all leaves of a plant originate from one coiled-up center. What doesn’t quite fit is the timeline: in October, the plan t should be dormant and the leaves gone, perhaps with a few dried-up remains.

@Stephie that should hold for Allium triqeutrum (three-cornered leek) as well, but I have fresh growth on mine at the moment and it's not the first time it's come up in autumn. For that matter the OP could be in the Southern hemisphere

@ChrisH no criticism, no dv, and I think we need a bit more input from the OP. Btw, location is Pennsylvania.

@Stephie good spot on the location. I'll edit it into the Q rather than it being buried in the comments.  I was commenting about the strange things plants do; your comment is correct as to how things ought to work

Thank you for the great responses. I don't think it's Allium ursinum because there isn't a garlic scent to them. The plant is starting to die now (it's drying up and turning to yellow). The photo I uploaded was taken earlier in the year. I can post a more recent image if that will be helpful.


Looks like lily of the valley.
